# How to pass entity atribute value to form Symfony2?

Tags: php, forms, class, symfony, attributes

I have a form type:

```
$builder->add('paises', 'collection', array(
                'options' => array('data_class' =>'Acc\ApssBundle\Entity\Pais'),
                'prototype' => true,
                'type' => new PaisType(),
                ))  ;
```

How to add attribute "name" to the class Pais to the label form ??

In twig I have:

```
{%  for pais in form.paises %}

<col>   

    <td>{{ form_label(pais.name)  }}</td>


</col>

{% endfor %}
```

Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Quick and dirty:**

It's not a solution but you could just as well do: `<td>{{ pais.vars.data.name }}</td>`.

**Proper way:**

Within `PaisType` setup the `FormEvent` so form is data-aware:

```
$builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) {
    $pais = $event->getData();
    $form = $event->getForm();

    # Use concreate data tp construct form field
    $form->add('some_custom_field_with_custom_label', 'text', array('label' => $pais->getName()));
});
```

Hope either of these help ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just expanding on @Jovan here

```
namespace App\Form\Type;

use App\Entity\Foobar;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\NumberType;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class FoobarType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) {
            $foobar = $event->getData();
            $form = $event->getForm();
        
            # Use concrete data to construct form field
            $form->add('foobarProperty',NumberType::class, array(
                'label' => $foobar->foobarMethod()
            ));
        });
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Foobar::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```