# Symfony2 static form collection labels

Tags: forms, symfony

I was looking over this part of the docs:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html

Except in my case each `tag` is a `question` has a unique label for each question.

How can I create unique labels for a collection form?

**QuestionType:**

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class QuestionType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('Answer', 'choice' array(
        'choices' => array(
                  '' => 'select one',
                  'yes',
                  'no')
        ));
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Acme\AcmeBundle\Entity\Question\Question',
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'question';
    }
}
```

**Questionare Collection:**

```
class BriefQuestionaireType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('Questions', 'collection', array(
            'type' => new QuestionType()
            )
        );
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Acme\AcmeBundle\Entity\Question\Questionaire',
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'briefquestionaire';
    }
}
```

I want to be able to do something like:

```
$builder->add('Questions', 'collection', array(
                'label' => 'Q1:Have you ever...?', //I'd like to use unique but static questions so that I can reuse the questions again later.`
                'type' => new QuestionType()
                )
            );


$builder->add('Questions', 'collection', array(
                'label' => 'Q2:Have you also...?', //I'd like to use unique but static questions so that I can reuse the questions again later.`
                'type' => new QuestionType()
                )
            );
```

However the above overwrites the previous label. So that only the label `Q2:Have you also...?` appears.

Hopefully now that it's more clear, that's what I meant when I said I wanted unique labels (which are just static questions) that have a yes/no choice selection.

Comment: What do you mean by unique labels for the collection? Like the first element of the collection gets label 'first tag`, the second element gets label 'some other tag', ... aso ?

Comment: Edited my question for more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need a single collection field. The "questions" array in the data you bind to the form will determine how many QuestionType fields are displayed. E.g...

```
// Acme/DemoBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php

// ...

$data = array(
    'Questions' => array(
        array('Answer' => 'First Answer'),
        array('Answer' => 'Second Answer'),
        array('Answer' => 'Third Answer')
    );
);

$form = $this->createForm(new BriefQuestionaireType(), $data);

// ...
```

The problem then is, how do you display unique labels for each Question field, when the options for all of them are exactly the same?

I ran into this problem the other day and solved it like this.

```
// Acme/DemoBundle/Form/LabelGenerator.php    

class LabelGenerator{

    private $labels;

    public function __construct(array $labels){
        $this->labels = $labels;
    }        

    public function __toString(){
        $keyValue = each($this->labels);
        return $keyValue['value'];
    }

}

// Acme/DemoBundle/Form/Type/BriefQuestionaireType.php

// ...

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {

    $labelGenerator = new LabelGenerator(array(
        'Q1: What is the first question?',
        'Q2: What is the second question?',
        'Q3: What is the third question?'
    ));

    $builder->add('Questions', 'collection', array(
        'type' => new QuestionType(),
        'options' => array(
            'label' => $labelGenerator    
        )
    ));

}

// ...
```

Every time the form theme renders a Question label, the LabelGenerator returns the next value in the array.

I recommend that you add a "question_labels" option to the BriefQuestionaireType form with setDefaultOptions(). You could then pass them to the collection like this.

```
// Acme/DemoBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php

// ...

$form = $this->createForm(new BriefQuestionaireType(), $data, array(
    'question_labels' => $labels
));

// ...

// Acme/DemoBundle/Form/Type/BriefQuestionaireType.php

// ...

public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver) {

    $resolver->setRequired(array('question_labels'));

}

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {

    $labelGenerator = new LabelGenerator($options['question_labels']);

    $builder->add('Questions', 'collection', array(
        'type' => new QuestionType(),
        'options' => array(
            'label' => $labelGenerator    
        )
    ));

}

// ...
```

Alternatively, if you want to get the labels from the Question entities, you could do it like this.

```
// Acme/DemoBundle/Form/Type/BriefQuestionaireType.php

// ...

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {

    $labels = array();
    foreach($builder->getData()->getQuestions() as $question){
        $labels[] = $question->getLabel();
    }

    $labelGenerator = new LabelGenerator($labels);

    $builder->add('questions', 'collection', array(
        'type' => new QuestionType(),
        'options' => array(
            'label' => $labelGenerator    
        )
    ));

}

// ...
```

Edit: You'll need to pre-fill Questions with the appropriate number of Question entities, otherwise you'll just have an empty collection.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm right about what you want to achieve I have answered similar question a week ago:

**[How to pass entity atribute value to form Symfony2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23564867/how-to-pass-entity-atribute-value-to-form-symfony2/23566602#23566602)**

Basically, solution relies on `FormEvent`s to convey data to `Form` and construct it's fields **dinamically**.

Comment: Very close! I actually want static labels in a collection so that I am able to reuse the form over and over in many places. Edited my question for more info btw.